# How to align view and subview center Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, alignment, cgrectmake

I have these two views that i would like to align to be centered.

```
self.loadingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 155, 120, 120)];
self.loadingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
self.loadingView.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;

self.activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
self.activityView.frame = CGRectMake(65, 40, self.activityView.bounds.size.width, self.activityView.bounds.size.height);

[self.loadingView addSubview:self.activityView];
```

loadingView needs to be aligned center to the iPhones screen. This means a code that can support different sizes of screens. And then activityView should be aligned centered inside the loadingView.

I have tried some code examples but none worked. And it was really confusing. If someone could provide some code exampels  and explaing a bit how it works to get a hang of this.

**EDIT1**

[image]

I wrote just as you did i added the self.view.center part but it is still not in the middle?

Also the second question was how to add the indicator view in the CENTER of the loadingView.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    self.view.backgroundColor= [UIColor blackColor];
    UIActivityIndicatorView * indicator;

            indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init];
            indicator.center = self.view.center;
            indicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
            [indicator startAnimating];
            [self.view addSubview:indicator];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

[image: iphone 6]

this will add the activity indicator in the center of the screen..

Comment: How do you create that default property?. I cant just write self.center it does not find anything when i do that?

Comment: its
 self.view.center

Comment: check my question, it is updated with a picture @magid